# How to assign function type to the class method?

Tags: typescript, types

Assigning function type to the variable is simple but what's the syntax to assign it to the method in the class?

type declaration:

```js
type SetDog = (id: string) => void
```

Assigning to variable(easy)

```js
const setDog: SetDog = (id) => setState(dog);
```

Now the question is how do we assign this type to the method in the class?

```js
class Dog {
  setDog(id) {
    setState(id);
  }
}
```

I can obviously set it on the method directly, but that's not the point here, I want to have this declaration abstracted.

```js
class Dog {
  setDog(id: string): void {
    setState(id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways you can solve this problem. The one you are looking for is probably declaring an arrow function as a class property. This way you can assign it a type (just like to any other property).

```
type SetDog = (id: string) => void;

class Dog {
    setDog: SetDog = (id) => {
        // Your code
    }
}

const dog = new Dog();
dog.setDog("puppy-123")
```

I don't think, however, this is a good design choice. It prevents you from abstracting your code later on. If I were you I would consider creating and implementing an interface. You can read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html).

```
interface Dog {
    setDog(id: string): void;
}

class Beagle implements Dog {
    setDog(id: string) {
        // ...
    }
}

class Yorkshire implements Dog {
    setDog(id: string) {
        // ...
    }
}

let dog: Dog = new Beagle();
dog.setDog("beagle-123");

// you wouldn't be able to make the follwing assignment
// if you continued with the first solution
dog = new Yorkshire();
dog.setDog("yorkshire-456");
```

Comment: Ah indeed! I forgot that I can use that syntax in TS! Thank you. 
Thanks for the architecture suggestion but I just made up that Dog class so it's easier to describe my issue. ; ). It may be helpful to someone else though.